# How to make numbers on log axis to become format of 10^i

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

As a beginner, I am plotting some data points using `ListLogLogPlot`. May I know is it possible to make all the numbers on x and y axes to appear as 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, instead of 0.1, 1, 10, etc. ?

[image]

Here is the code I use to plot the data points in log axes:

```
(*Data EF*)
EF = {{6.713329472805144`, 4.798728566747411`, 2.605948689531517`, 
    0.1751651588963768`, 0.044521739555961455`}, {6.683922382895504`, 
    4.785892414679682`, 3.0497788090671603`, 0.5684406939078067`, 
    0.2407333034352861`}, {6.4064763098145034`, 3.34985013297994`, 
    1.837210144328529`, 0.3680384898877517`, 
    0.1865277529403056`}, {4.695271123176444`, 1.2239371122572693`, 
    0.6089456965821706`, 0.12613160066194237`, 0.06502527257023452`}};
sList = {0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1};
TMList = {0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10};
miumaxList = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};

(*Function for tick formatting*)
GetScaledLogTicks[min_, max_, scale_] := 
  Module[{ticks}, 
   ticks = #[Log[min], 
       Log[max]] & /@ {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
      Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]};
   (*scale the tick length*)
   Table[{Exp[#[[1]]], #[[2]], scale*#[[3]]} & /@ ticks[[i]], {i, 2}]];
lticks = {GetScaledLogTicks[10^-3, 10, 3], 
   GetScaledLogTicks[0.1, 10, 3]};

(*Plotting EF*)
Bigplot = {};
legendColours = {};
legendEntries = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[sList], i++,
 EFdata = Transpose@{TMList, EF[[i]]};
 Bigplot = 
  Show[Bigplot, 
   ListLogLogPlot[EFdata, Joined -> True, 
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}, 
    PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1/Length[sList]*i, 0, 1], Thickness[0.01]},
     PlotRange -> {10^-3, 10}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Bold, 20], 
    FrameTicks -> lticks, AspectRatio -> 1]];
 legendColours = 
  Insert[legendColours, RGBColor[1/Length[sList]*i, 0, 1], i];
 legendEntries = 
  Insert[legendEntries, 
   StringTemplate["s = `a`"][<|"a" -> sList[[i]]|>]
   , i];]
Legended[Bigplot, 
 LineLegend[legendColours, legendEntries, 
  LegendLabel -> "s at miumax="[miumax]]]
```

Comment: Hello. Your code is quite long. It would be better to give a minimal example that illustrates your problem. A simple plot using the [Ticks option](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) to do the kind of thing you are asking would be `yticks=Table[{10^i,Superscript[10,i]},{i,1,4}]; LogPlot[(1.2+Sin[x])*Exp[x],{x,0,8},Ticks->{Automatic,yticks}]`. Perhaps you can adapt it to your problem.

Comment: This [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241997/22158) may be applicable.