# Ticks in scientific form with minor ticks to be shown in between

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
dataColinnn0 = {7*10^5, 3*10^5, 10*10^5, 10*10^5};
dataColinnn24 = {2*10^5, 0.5*10^5, 3*10^5, 1*10^5};
```

With the plot:

```
xvals = {0, 24};

dataColinnn = {#, 
 Around @@ 
  Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}@
    Symbol["dataColinnn" <> ToString@#]]} & /@ xvals;

 ListPlot[dataColinnn, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[0.1]}, {0, Scaled[0.1]}}, 
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {xvals, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Time (h)", FontSize -> 16, 
 FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
 Style["LOP", FontSize -> 16, 
 FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", 16, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[{Style["Numer of parents", FontSize -> 16, 
 FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10" ]}, Right], Mesh -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

My question is: How can I force the ticks on the y-axis to be shown in the scientific form?

There is a solution given in this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9558/how-to-express-ticks-in-scientific-form), but the minor ticks are disappeared.

**EDIT**

I found a solution to my comment to Jon McLoone's answer: to add NumberPoint -> ".0" to the ScientificForm in his answer:

```
Show[res, 
AbsoluteOptions[res, 
Ticks] /. {{a_Real, b_String /; b =!= "", c_List} :> {a, 
ScientificForm[a, NumberPoint -> ".0"], c}, 
x_FormBox :> DisplayForm[x]}]
```

which gives:

[image]

The only problem which remains is: how to remove $0$ after decimal in the origin of vertical axis? (To make it the same as origin for the horizontal axis, i.e., simply $0$)

Comment: Can you adapt [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241997/22158) to your plot?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for hackiness but here is a solution:
Where res is the plot that you have created, you can post-process the automatic ticks....

```
Show[res, 
 AbsoluteOptions[res, 
   Ticks] /. {{a_Real, b_String /; b =!= "", c_List} :> {a, 
     ScientificForm[a], c}, x_FormBox :> DisplayForm[x]}]
```